# Zend Framework HTTP 500

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, frameworks, internal-server-error

I am trying to copy a web application which uses Zend Framework to another domain. It crashes at the following line and returns an HTTP 500 error.

```
$application = new \Zend_Application(APPLICATION_ENV, $config);
```

If I add `die('1');` before this line, it displays `1`, but if I move it to after this line, it will show the HTTP 500 error.

I enabled displaying errors by:

```
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Any ideas?

**Edit: The error log**

```
[09-Dec-2016 13:37:01 Europe/Amsterdam] PHP Deprecated:  ini_set(): Use of mbstring.internal_encoding is deprecated in C:\xampp\htdocs\agv\current\site\vendor\bombayworks\zendframework1\library\Zend\Application.php on line 265

[09-Dec-2016 13:37:01 Europe/Amsterdam] PHP Warning:  require_once(/OLD_SITE_DIR/application/Bootstrap.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\site\current\site\vendor\bombayworks\zendframework1\library\Zend\Application.php on line 320

[09-Dec-2016 13:37:01 Europe/Amsterdam] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/OLD_SITE_DIR/current/site/application/Bootstrap.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\htdocs\agv\current\site\vendor/pear-pear.php.net/Event_Dispatcher;C:\xampp\htdocs\agv\current\site\vendor/pear-pear.php.net/HTML_AJAX;C:\xampp\htdocs\agv\current\site\vendor/pear-pear.php.net/HTML_Common;C:\xampp\htdocs\agv\current\site\vendor/pear-pear.php.net/HTML_QuickForm;C:\xampp\htdocs\agv\current\site\vendor/pear-pear.php.net/HTML_Template_Sigma;C:\xampp\htdocs\agv\current\site\vendor/pear-pear.php.net/Net_URL;C:\xampp\htdocs\agv\current\site\vendor/pear-pear.php.net/Net_Socket;C:\xampp\htdocs\agv\current\site\vendor/pear-pear.php.net/HTTP_Request;C:\xampp\htdocs\agv\current\site\vendor/pear-pear.php.net/Mail;C:\xampp\htdocs\agv\current\site\vendor/pear-pear.php.net/Net_DNS2;C:\xampp\htdocs\agv\current\site\vendor/pear-pear.php.net/XML_Util;C:\xampp\htdocs\agv\current\site\vendor/pear-pear.php.net/Structures_Graph;C:\xampp\htdocs\agv\current\site\vendor/pear-pear. in C:\xampp\htdocs\site\current\site\vendor\bombayworks\zendframework1\library\Zend\Application.php on line 320
```

Comment: Can you post the content of the error log?

Comment: @Philipp: Please find it in the description. Maybe I need to update references to the old directory?

Comment: Yeah - the problem is, Zend want to include the Bootstrap.php file, but couldn't find it in the '/OLD_SITE_DIR' - in your case it should be something like 'C:\xampp\htdocs\agv\'